# Android testing on Sauce Lab with selenium

Tags: android, python, selenium, saucelabs

I'm currently in the process of running a bunch of selenium tests on sauce lab. I won't to conduct my tests with all the android browsers, but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly specify that I want an android device. I've based my code on this template: http://saucelabs.com/examples/example.py

My code:

```
browsers = [{"platform": "Linux",
              "device-orientation" : "portrait",
              "version": "4.4"},
              {"platform": "Linux",
              "device-orientation" : "portrait",
              "deviceName" : "LG Nexus 4 Emulator",
              "version": "4.4"},
              {"platform": "Linux",
              "device-orientation" : "portrait",
              "deviceName" : "Samsung Galaxy S3 Emulator",
              "version": "4.4"},
              {"platform": "Linux",
              "device-orientation" : "portrait",
              "deviceName" : "Samsung Galaxy Nexus Emulator",
              "version": "4.4"},
              {"platform": "Linux",
              "device-orientation" : "portrait",
              "deviceName" : "Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator",
              "version": "4.4"}]

def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
            module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
    return decorator

@on_platforms(browsers)
class Mobile(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.desired_capabilities['name'] = self.id()

        sauce_url = "http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            desired_capabilities=self.desired_capabilities,
            command_executor=sauce_url % (USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY)
        )
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        #self.driver.set_window_size(500,1000)
        self.driver.get(test_site_url)

    # selecting car insurance by click the checkbox (F1)
    def test_f1_select_one_product_by_checkmark(self):
        element_name = "//label[@for='bil']//span[1]"
        productOption = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_name) 
        productOption.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired capabilities needed to spin up a Android session are a little different than what you have listed. Here is a set of capabilities that will work for a Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator session using Selenium.

```
caps = {'browserName': "android"}
caps['platform'] = "Linux"
caps['version'] = "4.4"
caps['deviceName'] = "Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator"
caps['deviceOrientation'] = "portrait"
```

Other Android configurations can designed found here:

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/